# Detect a server side FIN packet

Tags: java, tcp

I'm got the following Java code:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(mySockAddr, myTimeout);
```

Assuming I don't use the socket, I need to detect a server side connection close (`FIN` or `RST` packet) as soon as it happens.
For instance, though a thread which checks socket status, or intercepting the `FIN`/`RST` packets...

How can I detect it?
I've tried with `printWriter.checkError()`, `socket.isConnected()`, `socket.isClosed()` methods but nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

The only way i know of to detect whether the other side has closed the connection is by attempting to read from the input stream.  A read from a shut-down socket will return -1.  That's your notification that there won't be any more to read.

As far as the other functions go, `s.isConnected()` tells you whether you've successfully `connect()`ed the socket, and `s.isClosed()` would tell you whether *you* closed it.  It tells you nothing about what the other side has done.

Comment: First paragraph is correct apart from 'is the only read that will do so'. The rest is not so good: much of it would be better just omitted. Subsequent reads won't throw exceptions, they will just keep returning -1. isClosed() returns true if you have closed the socket and not otherwise.

Comment: @EJP: Like i said...it's been a while since i had to worry about it.  :P  Edited.